# Ĉu "eskalo" kaj "ŝtupetaro" estas sinonimoj?

Tags: word-difference

Are *"[eskalo](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/eskalo)"* and *"[ŝtupetaro](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/%C5%9Dtupetaro)"* synonyms, or is there any difference between the (probably at least greatly overlapping) meanings of these two terms? If the latter, what is the difference?

Ĉu *"[eskalo](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/eskalo)"* kaj *"[ŝtupetaro](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/%C5%9Dtupetaro)"* estas sinonimoj, aŭ estas malsameco inter la (verŝajne tre similaj) signifoj de tiuj du vortoj? Se estas diferenco, kio estas ĝi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIV (kiu estas iel nia norma vortaro) difinas [eskalo](http://vortaro.net/#eskalo) simple per *ŝtupetaro*. Do ili ja estas sinonimoj.

Tamen, kiel okazas kun ĉiuj radikoj, kelkaj povus diri al vi ke estas ia malsamo, rilate al ilia uzo aŭ tiu de iu komunumo.

Notu ke *eskal/* estas novradiko (neologismo) kaj *ŝtupetaro* normala Esperanta kunmetaĵo. Tio eble helpas vin decidi kiun uzi.

Answer (score 0):

Vi povas provi [Glosbe](https://en.glosbe.com/eo/en). Ĝi montras multajn malsamajn vortojn por ĉiu vorto.